# Why seemingly my email is not being sent with Meteor's email package?

Tags: email, meteor

I have a *Meteor* application and I am using the [email package](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/email_send). I was already using accounts (account-ui and account password) and recently set the `process.env.MAIL_URL` variable with a gmail account, tested the "reset password" functionality and got an email.

I was trying then to write code to receive an email (upon the user just clicking a button) basically to see this work, but I don't see the email "logged" in my console when running meteor locally.

If I do

```
 if(Meteor.isServer){
     Email.send({
      to: "to.address@email.com",
      from: "from.address@email.com",
      subject: "Example Email",
      text: "Text of the email."
    });
 })
```

I see a console message

[image: consolemessage]

(which is the same thing that I get if I click on "reset password" with the *account packages* functionality)

But I don't see this message upon invoking my own code, following the documentation instructions, which are plain simple.

I have a *serverMethods.js* file under /server which has

```
Meteor.methods({
  sendEmail: function (text) {

    check([text], [String]);

    this.unblock();
    Email.send({
      to: "to.address@email.com",
      from: "from.address@email.com",
      subject: "Example Email",
      text: text
    });
});
```

Then on client I am invoking like

```
Template.NavBar.events({
"click #testEmail" :function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
      Meteor.call('sendEmail', 'dataText');
  }
});
```

(being `testEmail` the ID of one item in my navBar template). Upon clicking, if I console.log I can see that my meteor call is being processed but I don't see in the console the same message as if the email was being sent.

What I'm missing must be pretty simple and obvious, given that the simplicity of this functionality explained in the documentation and that most tutorials I found about the topic basically just do the same thing. Still, I don't understand why I don't see the email logged in my console as it happens with the *accounts* functionality or if I invoke `Email.send` myself from server side.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's just a typo, but make sure you're setting the environment variable "MAIL_URL" not "MAIL_UR".

I find it easier to set it dynamically from a settings file (on the server side only):

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
    process.env.MAIL_URL = 'smtp://' + Meteor.settings.private.mail.username + ':' + Meteor.settings.private.mail.password + '@' + Meteor.settings.private.mail.smtpServer + '/';
});
```

Comment: Thanks. That was a typo when writing the question. As I said, I got the email functionality associated with _accounts password_ to work (so that ent var was set correctly). Also, even if I didn't have that variable, in my local env I would see the message on the console (warning that the email has not actually being sent and that the variable has to be sent). What puzzles me is that I don't see the message on console, even (apparently) following the docs instructions, and I can't se what is wrong or different in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this was silly after all. If you have the `process.env.MAIL_URL` you are not going to see the "Mail not sent; to enable sending, set the MAIL_URL environment variable." message logged in the console. This only displays if you don't have the variable set.

My problem was that I had the variable set, but I was not careful enough with the "to" email address used for my test. I was not sending the email to the right account, so I was not seeing any emails being sent nor any "fake" emails on the console.

So basically, with the `process.env.MAIL_URL` I only had to change

```
Email.send({
  to: "to.address@email.com", <--- Real address here
  from: "from.address@email.com",
  subject: "Example Email",
  text: text
});
```

to get emails being sent or remove the `process.env.MAIL_URL` to test it with spamming users.